# Creating custom tags

Tags: facebook, tags, comments

I knew that recently there was a bug that allowed you to tag someone without using their name.
Something along the lines of this: @@[0:[Facebook ID:0:Tag Name]]

This no longer seems to work. Is there anything in the api that will allow you to do the same? I am attempting to make a simple app that will allow people to easily create custom tags...

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has disabled the old tagging method `@@[0:[Facebook ID:0:Tag Name]]`, but have enabled tagging via the API (in limited form). Follow the [Mention Tagging](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) documentation.

You need to create an app and use actions in order to use it...